# Transaction failing

Tags: mysql, go, mariadb

I am writing an application in Go with a connector to MariaDb and I am getting the below error. When I paste the output manually into MySQL on the command line, it works perfectly. I'm not sure why it would be failing in the Go application.

```
BEGIN;
    INSERT INTO content (content) VALUES ('testing');
    SET @last_id_in_table1 = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    INSERT INTO article_meta
    (article_title, article_author, description)
    VALUES ('title', 'bob', '');
    SET @last_id_in_table2 = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    INSERT INTO articles
    (content_id, article_id)
    VALUES (@last_id_in_table1, @last_id_in_table2);
COMMIT;
    
2021/02/07 03:47:54 Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO content (content) VALUES ('testing');
    SET @last_id_in_table1 ...' at line 2
exit status 1
```

```
MariaDB [golang]> BEGIN;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [golang]> INSERT INTO content (content) VALUES ('testing');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [golang]> SET @last_id_in_table1 = LAST_INSERT_ID();
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [golang]> INSERT INTO article_meta
    -> (article_title, article_author, description)
    -> VALUES ('title', 'bob', '');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.056 sec)

MariaDB [golang]> SET @last_id_in_table2 = LAST_INSERT_ID();
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [golang]> INSERT INTO articles
    -> (content_id, article_id)
    -> VALUES (@last_id_in_table1, @last_id_in_table2);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.034 sec)

MariaDB [golang]> COMMIT;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.033 sec)
```

All other MySQL appears to work fine from the Go application. I can perform queries and inserts/updates without issue. I have no idea why this specific query is failing. Any help would be appreciated.

This is the specific code snippet in question:

```golang
query := fmt.Sprintf(`
  BEGIN;
    INSERT INTO content (content) VALUES ('%s');
    SET @last_id_in_table1 = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    INSERT INTO article_meta
    (article_title, article_author, description)
    VALUES ('%s', '%s', '%s');
    SET @last_id_in_table2 = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    INSERT INTO articles
    (content_id, article_id)
    VALUES (@last_id_in_table1, @last_id_in_table2);
  COMMIT;
`, article.Content, article.Title, article.Auth, article.Description)

fmt.Println(query)
rows, err2 := db.Query(query)
if err2 != nil {
    log.Fatal(err2)
}
```

Comment: You should use `tx, err := db.Begin()` to start a transaction, then invoke the *individual* statements with `tx.Query/QueryRow/Exec`, and then, if successful use `tx.Commit()` to commit that transaction or, if unsuccessful `tx.Rollback()` to abort.

Comment: Note also that using `%s` with `fmt.Printf` makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection. You should instead use "parameter placeholders" supported by the dbms and/or driver you're using. Like `?` in mysql or `$N` in postgres.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `tx, err := db.Begin()` to start a transaction, then invoke the individual statements with `tx.Query/QueryRow/Exec`, and then, if successful use `tx.Commit()` to commit that transaction or, if unsuccessful `tx.Rollback()` to abort.

Note also that using `%s` with `fmt.Printf` makes your code vulnerable to SQL injection. You should instead use "parameter placeholders" supported by the dbms and/or driver you're using. Like `?` in mysql or `$N` in postgres.

Something like the following should work:

```golang
func insertArticle(a *Article) (err error) {
    tx, err := db.Begin()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer func() {
        if err != nil {
            tx.Rollback()
        }
    }()
    
    res, err := tx.Exec("INSERT INTO content (content) VALUES (?)", a.Content)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    contentId, err := res.LastInsertId()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    res, err = tx.Exec("INSERT INTO article_meta (article_title, article_author, description) VALUES (?, ?, ?)", a.Title, a.Auth, a.Description)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    articleId, err := res.LastInsertId()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    
    _, err = tx.Exec("INSERT INTO articles (content_id, article_id) VALUES (?, ?)", contentId, articleId)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    
    return tx.Commit()
}
```